# Setting Line Spacing for Word 2007, in Culturally Neutral Way

Tags: c#, ms-word, spacing

I am having trouble setting the line spacing in Word 2007. Word 2007 defaults to double spacing or to having extra space between lines. Previously, I have always used something similar to this with success (In C#):

```
//No spacing when using Word version > 2003
//Word 2003 = "11.0"
//Word 2007 = "12.0"
Word.Application appVersion = new Word.Application();
string sVersion = appVersion.Version.ToString();
if (sVersion != "11.0")
{
    object noSpacingStyle = "No Spacing";
    oWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.set_Style(ref noSpacingStyle);
}
```

But, this is breaking when trying to apply it under some regional/cultural settings, such as Italian and German. I believe this is because "No Spacing" needs to be in the target language, instead of hardcoded as English. So, I am trying to figure out a way to apply this same change in a more portable way.

I've tried sifting through the various enumerations, such as "WdBuiltinStyle," but can't seem to find one that accomplishes the same thing as "No Spacing."

Does anyone here know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about using

```
Selection.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = WdLineSpacing.wdLineSpaceSingle;
```

Your code does not set the line spacing, it sets a style that has certain line spacing applied to it.

Quoting from the person asked how they solved it, since this is the accepted answer:

> As Joey suggested, the solution is to use Word's built in styles. I
>   resolved this by applying the following to my Word._Application
>   object:
>
> ```
> oWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = Word.WdLineSpacing.wdLineSpaceSingle;
> oWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0.0F;
> ```

Comment: Thank you, Joey. However, it seems that "Word.WdLineSpacing.wdLineSpaceSingle" doesn't get rid of the extra line spacing completely because I believe is also another setting getting in the way. When using the standard interface in Word, this setting can be seen under Paragraph, in the Spacing section, in which "After:" is set to 10pt be default. So, I think that has to be manipulated as well somehow, though I do not know how to manipulate it.

Comment: Joey, I worked out the rest. See my answer below for details. Thank you for leading me to the solution!

Answer (score 1):

As Joey suggested, the solution is to use Word's built in styles. I resolved this by applying the following to my Word._Application object:

```
oWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = Word.WdLineSpacing.wdLineSpaceSingle;
oWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0.0F;
```